# Lot of documentation split across several documents

Tags: documentation

Going through

```
https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/
```

There is a lot of documentation and is currently split across several documents.  When people give the advice of going through the documentation, such advice is not of much use.  Can the Latex Team explain better where to look for things under specific categorisations?

For instance I have the following that numbers according to section

```
\newtheorem{galex-theorem}{Theorem}[section]
```

But cannot find the documentation that would allow me to number according to theorem.

The following gives an error

```
\newtheorem{galex-corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
```

Comment: You can search on CTAN. There are many categories there.

Comment: Well, depends on what you need. Documentation for specific packages can be found via the `texdoc` utility, texdoc.org, or CTAN. For the LaTeX kernel the names are somewhat speaking, user command documentation? `usrguide`. Class/package-author information? `clsguide`. Font setup? `fntguide`. LaTeX3 stuff? `usrguide3` (document level), `interface3` (`expl3` function interfaces), `expl3` (short general introduction to `expl3`). (Disclaimer: I'm not a LaTeX-team member)

Comment: A different solution is called "book", available from book stores. // You can also create your own 1-doc version by e.g. assembling everything into an ebook-format, or print as pdf and merge several ones.

Comment: Yes, but I am convinced that the Latex Team should do their best to help users find the information they need.  Putting thousands and thousands of pages without a guide to it only ends up frustrating users.

Comment: One problem is that there are thousands of packages, each with 10+ pages.  Creating a guide for that would be difficult at best.  But you look like you're using `\newtheorem` from the package `amsthm`.  In that case, typing `texdoc amsthm` on your command line might be the place to start.

Comment: I am only interested in the basic build in commands, not even from `amsthm` actually.  Even more basic that that.  Does the `built-in` Latex commands allow sectioning by theorem numbering?  I think that the theorem construct is actually built-in without any requirements from `amsthm`.  Regarding packages by others, then it is the responsibility of the package maintainer to provide decent way to go through his documentation.   Otherwise, there will be many who would simply discard such packages.

Comment: I am amazed how nobody is able to give a one line solution in the failure in `\newtheorem{galex-corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]`.  Have done a search on `theorem` through the various documentations on the website, but did not lead to anything that I can instantly understand and use.

Comment: learn to make proper questions with complete examples then you will also get proper answers and not only bewildered comments from people trying to guess what you are up to.

Comment: I am looking at the options one can use in the third argument besides `[theorem]` for the command `\newtheorem`.

Comment: The third argument can be any counter. See page 744 of [source2e](https://ctan.org/pkg/source2e?lang=en) which documents the kernel source code "for the entire system as one document". The site you linked to has another page dedicated to [LaTeX books](https://www.latex-project.org/help/books/), which might be closer to what you're looking for. Arugably Knuth's *TeXbook* and Lamport's *LaTeX: A Document Preparation System* are the "official" documentation by the respective creators of TeX and LaTeX. The *LaTeX Companion* is fairly exhaustive as well.

Comment: I have looked at the code where I found `[section]` in file `./required/tools/theorem.dtx`.  How is it that the documentation does not list the built-in counter options.  I seem to think that what I should use is `[Theorem]`, but cannot find it within the code distribution.  Is is somewhat confusing that ordinarily one finds `[section]` for the section numbering, but for theorem numbering the counter `[Theorem]` is capitalised.

Comment: if you have defined `theorem` the code you show would work, if you have not, what do you mean by "number according to theorem." As far as I can tell, you want `\newtheorem{galex-corollary}{Corollary}[galex-theorem]` but you have not provided any example code in either question